# Updating multiple columns in a row in MSSQL Server with python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, github

```
SQLUpdateCommand = ("Update prodtbl set CompanyAddress=?, UserName=?, FromEmailAddress=?, paswrd=? WHERE CompanyName=?")

        Values = [CompanyName, CompanyAddress, UserName, FromEmailAddress, paswrd, CompanyName]

         print("Upto Here It executes Successfully. After this it fails..!<br/>")
        cursor.execute(SQLUpdateCommand,Values)
        cnxn.commit()
```

*The above values are assigned to the respective variables.

Since the CompanyName is repeated twice. So error occured.

After the print statement below the code results in error.

How to catch the exception and print the same exception raised?*

Comment: Please include the error and the traceback.

Comment: For a start, `Values` contains 6 items but you only provided bindings for 5 in your statement. Why do you have `CompanyName` at index 0 in your list, it looks like you can just remove that.

Comment: I'm confused after your edit. Your example is to _deliberately_ throw an exception in order to test how to catch it? You still haven't included the error and traceback.

Comment: No not like that. I have an CompanyName repeated twice. So error occurs. How do I update the CompanyName. I wil try to assign another variable and  swap. Let me see now. In order to catch the exception in web browser how to code that?

Comment: Even assign like this Values = [CompName, CompanyAddress, UserName, paswrd, FromEmailAddress, CompanyName] Causes error @roganjosh

Comment: @roganjosh I have not configured exception in right manner so that I could not print it on web browser correctly.                                                                                         except :
  print("<br/>Query Failed")
  cursor.close()
  cnxn.close()

Comment: I think I have not created company_ID Think so...

Comment: I really have no idea what all those comments mean. All you need to do is `Values = [CompanyAddress, UserName, FromEmailAddress, paswrd, CompanyName]`.